# Linear Algebra - subspace proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times{n}}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times{1}}$. Show that $Ax = b$ solution set

$R = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times{1}}$$:Ax = b\}$

is a $\mathbb{R}^{n\times{1}}$ subspace if and only if $b = 0$

Looking for hints how to start proving this (looking for a starting point, not the answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint for "if": assume $b=0$, then consider $x,y \in R$ we want to show that $R$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. You can use the linearity property of $A$ to do this.

"only if": assume $R$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. Again use the linearity of $A$.

Comment: thank you, solved it.